# If I enable 32bit applications for a site in IIS7 I get a 500 error

Tags: iis-7, 32-bit

If I enable 32bit applications for any site on IIS7 2008 it triggers a 500 server error.

Comment: I tried to enable failed request tracing the but no error logs are being written in the directory. I can't even get a 404 error to generate, it seems to be something before the server can even look at a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Default Application Pool was stopped. Restarted it and it was fine. :-/